# Variable Length Array Performance Implications (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm writing a fairly straightforward function that sends an array over to a file descriptor.  However, in order to send the data, I need to append a one byte header.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing and it seems to work:

```
void SendData(uint8_t* buffer, size_t length) {
  uint8_t buffer_to_send[length + 1];
  buffer_to_send[0] = MY_SPECIAL_BYTE;
  memcpy(buffer_to_send + 1, buffer, length);
  // more code to send the buffer_to_send goes here...
}
```

Like I said, the code seems to work fine, however, I've recently gotten into the habit of using the Google C++ style guide since my current project has no set style guide for it (I'm actually the only software engineer on my project and I wanted to use something that's used in industry).  I ran Google's cpplint.py and it caught the line where I am creating buffer_to_send and threw some comment about not using variable length arrays.  Specifically, here's what Google's C++ style guide has to say about variable length arrays...

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Variable-Length_Arrays_and_alloca__

Based on their comments, it appears I *may* have found the root cause of seemingly random crashes in my code (which occur very infrequently, but are nonetheless annoying).  However, I'm a bit torn as to how to fix it.

Here are my proposed solutions:

1. Make buffer_to_send essentially a fixed length array of a constant length.  The problem that I can think of here is that I have to make the buffer as big as the theoretically largest buffer I'd want to send.  In the average case, the buffers are much smaller, and I'd be wasting about 0.5KB doing so each time the function is called.  Note that the program must run on an embedded system, and while I'm not necessarily counting each byte, I'd like to use as little memory as possible.
2. Use new and delete or malloc/free to dynamically allocate the buffer.  The issue here is that the function is called frequently and there would be some overhead in terms of constantly asking the OS for memory and then releasing it.
3. Use two successive calls to write() in order to pass the data to the file descriptor.  That is, the first write would pass only the one byte, and the next would send the rest of the buffer.  While seemingly straightforward, I would need to research the code a bit more (note that I got this code handed down from a previous engineer who has since left the company I work for) in order to guarantee that the two successive writes occur atomically.  Also, if this requires locking, then it essentially becomes more complex and has more performance impact than case #2.

Note that I cannot make the buffer_to_send a member variable or scope it outside the function since there are (potentially) multiple calls to the function at any given time from various threads.

Please let me know your opinion and what my preferred approach should be.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is behind the file descriptor?  The impact of multiple write calls varies with the target.  Also, do you have a "hard" bound on length?

Comment: My hard bound on length is huge, I'd prefer not to have a bunch of unneeded memory allocated each time the function is called.  Also, the file descriptor is essentially a connection to a serial device.

Comment: Did you consider using `writev()`? It is intended to splice multiple buffers into one, using the equivalent of a `write()`  with one buffer.

Comment: Is this a leaf function?  If it is, you don't need to worry so much about avoiding large stack allocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fold the two successive calls to write() in your option 3 into a single call using writev().

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/writev.html

Comment: Exactly what I needed!  Thanks for introducing me to another built in function I never knew existed, but I (now) absolutely cannot live without!

Answer (score 0):

I would choose option 1. If you know the maximum length of your data, then allocate that much space (plus one byte) on the stack using a fixed size array. This is no worse than the variable length array you have shown because you *must* always have enough space left on the stack otherwise you simply won't be able to handle your maximum length (at worst, your code would randomly crash on larger buffer sizes). At the time this function is called, nothing else will be using the further space on your stack so it will be safe to allocate a fixed size array.

Comment: Is 'int x[length+1]` allocated on the stack or heap?

Comment: @koodawg: Variable length arrays like that are allocated in automatic storage (the stack).